# How can I remove Linux from my system?

Tags: linux, windows-xp

My system contains both Windows XP and Linux 2.6 31-14 generic. I want to install a new version of Linux, but it is only possible after removing the older version. What are the steps to do it? It should not affect my Windows XP.

Comment: Do you mean Linux in general or just replacing it with a new Kernel? Which distribution do you want to install?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever A Linux system is installed alongside with another operating system like windows. Each one resides on a different partition. Where Windows is naming those partitions like **C: D:** and so on, they are named different in linux. Like **/dev/sda1 /dev/sdb2** and the like. Where **sda** is the first harddisk, **sdb** is the second. **sda1** is the first partition of the harddisk, **sda2** the second and so on. If you use logical partitions, you must use them as a work around because you can not create more than 4 physical partitions, they start with the number 5. Like **/dev/sda5** You can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_partition_%28virtual_computing_platform%29) for further understanding.

In Linux those Partitions and disks  are shown if you type the following command:

```
sfdisk -l
```

Now have a look at the table outputted to the screen. The partition where it says something with ntfs or fat is your windows partition. If the command *sfdisk* isn't found you have to install the package sfdisk.

Just make sure you are not override this when installing a new Linux Distribution. Use the advanced tools when the installer asks you for partitioning the hard disk. And use the one which already has Linux installed. Most Distributions will detect the windows and will add those partition rather than overriding it and adding a boot menu entry to your grub [bootloader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootloader#Boot_loader) (the one which is used to boot linux.) You also may use the windows bootloader to load linux as described [here](http://www.icpug.org.uk/national/linnwin/step2-xp.htm)

You also may use *mount* or *df*. But these commands not showing all the partitions and disk. Just the one mounted. And the partition your windows resides on may not be mounted.

However if you just want to change the kernel on which Linux is running you must setup your bootloader. Assuming this is grub /grub2. This is well documented [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB_Legacy)